# How might I add Cases to Contacts in bulk?

Tags: civicase

I am building new workflows and want to add Cases to Individual Contacts retrospectively. Is it possible to add Cases in bulk (ie one Case of Type "XXX" per selected Contact)?.
I would then need to bulk update the resulting Cases to apply set values both for the Case Status and for certain Activities in the Case Files, though those latter steps should be relatively straightforward.

Comment: Similar question: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/12214/is-is-possible-to-import-cases-into-civi

Comment: check API cvs Importer extension. https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-csv-import-gui